# what to use in place of marjoram in vegetable soup

Tags: substitutions

What can I use in place of marjoram in vegetable soup?  The recipe already calls for oregano.

Comment: Hi Barbara. Welcome to Seasoned Advice! It would be helpful if you shared more about the soup in question so we know what kind of other flavors are involved.

Comment: Don't use anything. Marjoram isn't essential, especially if oregano is already included. Just up the oregano a bit instead.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you know that marjoram is closely related to oregano; so if you don't want to use marjoram (or don't have it) you can just omit it or use a bit more oregano. If not already called for, you could also use other herbs that are generally compatible like parsley, sage, or thyme.